# Can not install pymssql

Tags: python

Using the command as shown in the image, I am unable to import the package pymssql
[image]

i basically need to install this package so that I can get a file on the SQL database directly using python.

Comment: Use `!pip install pymssql`. Pay attention to `!` at the start.

Comment: Still not working. I have tried numerous syntax to install this package but some error or the other always remains. Or is there any other way to read a sql file in Python?
Gives me this message "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"